# Excel: count number of common parameters for two values

Tags: excel, count

I have a list of materials with for each materials the parts that compose them.
I would like to count for every possible material combination the number of common parts.

```
material    part
mat 1       b
mat 1       c
mat 2       b
mat 2       e
mat 3       c
mat 3       b



        mat 1   mat 2   mat3
mat 1             1      2
mat 2       1            1
mat 3       2     1
```

mat 1 & mat 3 have two common parts: b & c
mat 1 & mat 2 have one common part: b
etc...

Can I easily do this with a formula or will I need VBA for this?

Thank you for your help

FG

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your first table in `A1:B8` and second in `A11:D14` then try this "array formula" in B12 confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> and copied across and down

`=IF(B$11=$A12,"",SUM(($A$2:$A$7=B$11)*ISNUMBER(MATCH($B$2:$B$7,IF($A$2:$A$7=$A12,$B$2:$B$7),0))))`

see example workbook [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/j3vezbxg84je1u6/Book1.xls)

Comment: What would I do with my life otherwise?